# Convert frequency table to raw data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sensor. For some reasons, the sensor like to record data like this:

```
>df
        obs  count
       -0.3    3
        0.9    2
        1.4    5
```

i.e. it first records observations and make a count table out of it. What I would like to do it convert this df into a series with raw observations. For example, I would like to end up with: [-0.3,-0.3,-0.3,0.9,0.9,1.4,1.4 ....]

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039574/generate-column-of-raw-data-based-on-frequency-table-in-excel) asked for excel.

Comment: df['obs'] is count of how many times a given value appeared. Since most library expect raw data, it is difficult to work with freq table.

Comment: Since the original order info has been lost, you realize that there isn't a unique mapping from frequency counts to raw observations right?

Comment: Yes I understand that. Order is not of importance. all the data is basically recorded in fraction of second.

Comment: `df['obs'].repeat(df['count'])` will give you a new Series... you could then use `.tolist()` on that... I'm guessing that's what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe structure is like this one (or similar):

```
       obs  count
    0 -0.3      3
    1  0.9      2
    2  1.4      5
```

This is an option, using numpy.repeat:

```
   import numpy as np

   times = df['count'] 

   df2['obs'] = np.concatenate([np.repeat(df['obs'],times)])

   print(df2)

          obs
       0 -0.3
       1 -0.3
       2 -0.3
       3  0.9
       4  0.9
       5  1.4
       6  1.4
       7  1.4
       8  1.4
       9  1.4
```

Comment: If you want to use `numpy.repeat` instead of `pandas.Series.repeat` then you don't really need to concatenate things... just `np.repeat(df['obs'], df['count'])` is fine... Or, also methods available in pandas, then: `df['obs'].repeat(df['count'])` will do the same

Comment: I am not sure of this solution you propose. Try it: df2 = np.repeat(df['obs'], df['count']) and print df2. All elements "-0.3" got the index 0,  all "0.9" are indexed as 1 and all "1.4" are indexed as 2. Depending  on what you want you can get your dataframe useless.

Comment: then just add a `.reset_index()` (eg: `df['obs'].repeat(df['count']).reset_index()`) - however, it doesn't appear the OP cares about the index anyway - more they're just after repeated values...

Comment: The use of concatenate seems a neat aproach to me. But thanks to the suggestion. By the way, loved the ninja dog in your profile picture. :-)